# Sum of rows on XLSX Sheet (with a header) + Sum of column (IN POWERSHELL)

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an XLSX file named DOM-TEST-JJMMYYYY which includes a header

```
    Sequence    Number  Subscriber  Code    Name    Channel Date    Date end    Amount  Total   State

    000655  KDZ_SSFA/493J39 141230  3393Jd  XXX, Amber  -   01-01-1999  02-01-2022  29,50   0   Approved

    000658  KDZ_SFA/893J39  181230  3398Jd  XXX, Manuel -   01-01-2021  02-01-2022  23,20   0   Approved

    ...
```

The script I want (in powershell) should read an xlsx file, count the number of rows for the first sheet, and the total amount (a rounded sum of the "Amount" column). The goal of the script is to rename the file like this :

DOM-TEST-JJMMYYYY**-LLLLLL-MMMMMMM.XLSX**

Where

LLLLLL = Number of line without pre-zeros

MMMMMMM = rounded sum of the "amount" column

I'm blocked here in my code. I'm still learning PowerShell and very much a beginner so I have no idea how to approach this

```
$sheetname = "Sheet1"
$file = "C:/Data/DOM-TEST-01-01-2022"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetname)
$objExcel.Visible=$false

$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
```

Can you help me to move further please ?
thank you !

Comment: Don't tag spam. Why do you tag lots of powershell versions? They're only for problems specifically in that version

Answer (score 0):

> Number of line without pre-zeros

Assuming that you have the serials stored as text so there are zeros there for Excel to look for, choose an empty cell to put a formula in so Excel will do the work, and read the result:

```
$sheet.Range("N1").Formula = '=COUNTIF(A:A, "0*")'
$sheet.Range("N1").Text
# 2
```

> and the total amount (a rounded sum of the "Amount" column).

Assuming that your locale uses `22,50` for its decimal point and Excel understands that:

```
$sheet.Range("N1").Formula = '=ROUND(SUM("I:I"), 0)'
$sheet.Range("N1").Text
```

Mine doesn't, I would have to convert them to "22.50" but I think this will work if yours does.