# Rename an xslx file with the right info using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an XLSX file named DOM-TEST-JJMMYYYY which includes a header

```
    Sequence    Number  Subscriber  Code    Name    Channel Date    Date end    Amount  Total   State

    000655  KDZ_SSFA/493J39 141230  3393Jd  XXX, Amber  -   01-01-1999  02-01-2022  29,50   0   Approved

    000658  KDZ_SFA/893J39  181230  3398Jd  XXX, Manuel -   01-01-2021  02-01-2022  23,20   0   Approved

    ...
```

The script I want (in powershell) should read an xlsx file, count the number of rows for the first sheet, and the total amount (a rounded sum of the "Amount" column). The goal of the script is to rename the file like this :

DOM-TEST-JJMMYYYY**-LLLLLL-MMMMMMM.XLSX**

Where

LLLLLL = Number of line without pre-zeros

MMMMMMM = rounded sum of the "amount" column

I'm still learning PowerShell and very much a beginner so I have no idea how to approach this. I'm blocked here in my code. I prefer a solution where we don't use formula inside the file.

```
$sheetname = "Sheet1"
$file = "C:/Data/DOM-TEST-01-01-2022"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetname)
$objExcel.Visible=$false

$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
```

Can you help me to move further please ?
thank you !

[image]

Comment: Please don't [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73110359/9898643) the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Excel file has the headers in the first row, this should work:

```
$sheetname = "Sheet1"
$file      = "C:\Data\DOM-TEST-01-01-2022.xlsx"

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false

$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet    = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetname)
$sheet.Activate()

$rowMax = $sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
$colMax = $sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
$columnIndex = 0
$totalAmount = 0

# get the index for column 'Amount'
for ($col = 1; $col -le $colMax; $col++) {
    $name = $sheet.Cells.Item(1, $col).Value()  
    if ($name -eq 'Amount') { $columnIndex = $col; break }
}

if ($columnIndex) {
    # sum the values in this column in variable $totalAmount
    for ($row = 2; $row -le $rowMax; $row++) {
        $totalAmount += ($sheet.Cells.Item($row, $columnIndex).Value2 -as [double])
    }
}

$objExcel.Quit()
# IMPORTANT: clean-up used Com objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

# You can now rename the file using the $rowMax and $totalAmount values
$newFileName = '{0}-{1}-{2:F0}.xlsx' -f [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file), $rowMax, $totalAmount
Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName $newFileName
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response and for the effort. 
I have these errors when I run the script in powershell (see EDIT)

Comment: Perfect it works ! don't know why you need to add this to run the script :
[threading.thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 'en-US'

There's only one problem. it concerns the number of rows. Normally it should be 8 for my file but it print "10".

Comment: I made another variable $AdjustedMaxRow = $MaxRow - 2. It seems OK for any case. thank you !

Comment: @amin89 I couldn't see your Excel file, but maybe there is something in a row just beneath the actual data, so the rowcount gets larger than needed. Perhaps more precise would be to do 
`$firstDataRow = $worksheet.Cells($worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).End($xlUp).Row; $lastDataRow  = $worksheet.Cells($firstRow, 1).End($xlDown).Row; $firstRow++ # skip the header row` and then loop using
`for ($row = $firstDataRow; $row -le $lastDataRow; $row++) { $totalAmount += ($sheet.Cells.Item($row, $columnIndex).Value2 -as [double]) }`. Anyway, glad to hear my answer helped.

Comment: @amin89 P.S. `$xlUp = -4162` and `$xlDown = -4121`. See these constants [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldirection)

Comment: Just for my knowledge, when you put {0}-{1}-{2:F0}.xlsx,what does mean the braces brackets ? are they arguments ? and what do you mean by {2:F0} ? thanks !

Comment: @amin89 That syntax is for using the [-f Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f). A very clean way of building a string using numbered placeholders. The `{2:F0}` inserts the $totalAmount value formatted as Floating-point, rounded to 0 decimals